# route.exe: command not found in bashrc - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an issue with route.exe in the bashrc of ubuntu. Basically I am using ubuntu 20.04 in wsl in windows. I am trying to get the ip using the route.exe. It was working fine earlier but now it is not working. The bashrc is as follows:

```
export PATH="/home/srkpmlz/.local/bin:/home/srkpmlz/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local"
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
export SVGA_VGPU10=0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')
export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0
export DOCKER_GATEWAY_HOST="`/sbin/ip route|awk '/dev eth0 proto kernel/ { print  $9}'`"
```

and after editing, when i try to source the bashrc i am getting the error:

```
route.exe: command not found
route.exe: command not found
```

what may be the reason ?

The bashrc is sourced and working

Comment: Is `route.exe` in any of the directories you put on your `PATH`? (As an aside, you both *replaced* the entire inherited `PATH` rather than appending to it, and you have a likely typo--`>`--at the end of the new value.)

Comment: This is why you generally prepend or append to your PATH instead of replacing it outright.

Comment: @chepner I guess the symbol at the last of the PATH is a typo. I replaced it. But still no improvement. I just need to access the WLAN address. Is there any other commands available other than this ? i tried ***'$(ip -4 addr show scope global | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1)'*** but it returns the Ethernet ip address.

Comment: UPDATE: I added the route.exe path to the export PATH and now it is working. It was working without the route.exe path earlier. Donno why?

Comment: "Route.exe" is a Windows program you try to run in a Linux environment. Why do you think this is even possible?

Comment: I mean i am trying to run in ubuntu in wsl2. As per the previous comments, i added the win32 directory to the PATH variable and now i can use the route.exe

Answer (score 0):

**.exe** is an executable file to Windows. We use run "exe" file emulation through "Wine" software, but not for professional use.

your bashrc conf is default or did you edit it?

maybe a valid binary to your variables be only "route"

```
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(route print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')
export DISPLAY=$(route print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0
```

**[suggestion]** we can change the exports above by:

```
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(ip -4 addr show scope global | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1)
export DISPLAY=$(ip -4 addr show scope global | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1):0.0
```

Test if "route" command exists, otherwise theses variables definitions do will not work,or you can use "ip addr" instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How can i modify it? i tried **$echo $(awk '/0[.]0[.]0[.]0/ { match=$4 } END { print match }')**  but never worked !

Comment: @RonyShaji then we overcome the route binary, now you need adjust the command "route print", in old linux version, this command get a route table.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Did you read the question? we are debating about route binary, we aren't talking about "grep | head | awk" or Wine. I suggested a way to him test the binary and explained about .exe extension. Idk why he use "grep | head | awk", he knows why.

Comment: @MarceloGuedes I didnot understand what you mean by overcome the route binary. can you suggest what can i use there instead ?

Comment: so sorry @RonyShaji i meant that we got over this issue, why initially you had a issue with the "route.exe". Now we need adjust the command "route print"

Comment: @MarceloGuedes Doesn't work either...i just want to access the WLAN address of the windows. I was indeed working earlier with route.exe but not now...now i am manually typing the ip address from ipconfig/all.

Comment: @RonyShaji look at my update on the answer, see if this can help you.

Comment: But _you_ are talking about WINE in the answer, incorrectly implying that it's necessary even on WSL. One can natively run Windows executables from WSL, though not with an overridden PATH as the OP is setting up.